# What are the Steps to follow to update web.config in an IIS webserver

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, refresh

I am new to web development. We are having a legacy intranet web application using ASP.NET web forms.

We have encrypted web.config using `ASPNET_REGIIS tool` for the connection strings, based on security feedback. I am able to test it locally using IISExpress.

What are the steps to follow to update the old web.config with new web.config, in an environment.

We need to update web.config in multiple environments(DEV,TEST, UAT) before refreshing in production.

We will be announcing downtime for the same. Please list down the steps like resetting IIS etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do below steps:

1. **First and Foremost:** Took a backup of existing web.config, so that, if something goes wrong, I can fallback to original web.config
2. As web.config encryption is machine specific, I encrypted the web.config using ASPNET_REGIIS tool, as mentioned in the [codeproject Link](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/795135/encrypt-connectionstring-in-web-config)
3. Web.config changes are automatically picked by IIS. I did not have to restart IIS or recycle APPPool. The site was working fine with the new web.config changes, I made.

Answer (score 1):

Since the key used for encrypt/decrypt is different on different server. You can decrypt the connection string section before publishing. Then just override the web.config on your target server, then encrypt the connection string with asp_regiis tool again. You can find aspnet_regiis under the root folder of .NET framework.

Of course, there is a way to sync up RSA container for mutiple servers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/yxw286t2(v=vs.100)

After that, please don't forget to grant permission for machinekey file in \Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys.

Finally you just have to recyle the application pool.

Comment: We have already encrypted the connection string and tested the web applicaiton. It is working fine. In the server, can we simply override the web.config . What should we do in the downtime announced ? like iis stop, iis start etc. can you please tell step by step. It will be a good reference.